# Pop Up Thank You Message

Tags: javascript, forms, popup

I am a graphic designer with some knowledge in HTML, CSS and Javascript. My coding knowledge is a bit rusty as I have not developed for years.

I need to make a "Thank you" popup message for a site that I am developing. From my previous knowledge I know that JavaScript can do it, but is there any way to do this without JavaScript? I would like the site to function the same for those without JavaScript enabled.

Answer (score 2):

In this age of increasing use of dynamic websites, if people want to turn off JavaScript then that's their loss and tough nuggets to them if the website doesn't work.

However, if you're submitting a form, either:

- You are submitting it to another page. Just have this page show a thank you message as part of its content.
- You are using AJAX to submit it, in which case you already require JavaScript so shouldn't be worried about people not having it enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CSS Modal box. By using stuff like a `div` with `position:fixed`, for example, you could add a `div` on the middle of your screen on top of everything else, thus rendering a custom box. The problem is that you might need to do the controlling of the div style through javascript. You could also do so redirecting to another page with the CSS box.

I think it's fine doing so in javascript. Maybe flash would be a bit more problematic. HTML5 even worst, right now.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you can use CSS to create a Modal. Using an overlay class and turning its visibility to show or hide on screen will work and changing its background-color property to a solid color desired and lower the opacity.

```
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #0000007a;
    transition: opacity 200ms;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
}
```